# When do UICollectionView @required method's get called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am working on UICollectionView and have a question as to how/when the method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)asker 
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

gets called. The parameters that it has are a UICollectionView, which is obviously the CollectionView that is in your Controller's view. The index path I think is just the index for a specific cell that has been allocated into the CollectionView. So, my question is :

When does this method get called? Does it get called as I scroll inside of the UICollectionView and it is needing to populate with items? Or maybe when the view get's instantiated, it will call this to populate its CollectionView.

Also what happens if I have two UICollectionView's in the same view? Would I use this method and just call:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)cell
                                                    forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

twice within the method and state two different reuse identifier's and utilize them how I wish?

Also like the title say's, when do the @required method's get called? Do they all get called in this sort of a fashion?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `asker` parameter is the collection view whose `delegate` is the class in which you've implemented that method. By default, if you've created your UICollectionViewController in Xcode with an associated xib, it's the UICollectionView in your view and the delegate is already setup, as you say.

The method `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` gets called whenever the collection view needs the cell for the specified index path. The actual implementation is private, but we can infer that it gets called whenever it thinks a cell is about to become visible (because the user is scrolling, for example). And of course when the collection view first appears all the cells that will be visible are loaded.

If you have 2 collection views with the same delegate then you will need to compare the `asker` parameter to your properties/ivars to figure out which collection view is asking for the cell and set your reuse identifier appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, Jeff! Do all of the method's as apart of the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol run when either the CollectionView first appears in the view? Like the method's numberOfSectionInCollectionView and - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section?

Comment: Typically, yes. You can drop some log functions in to test it yourself. The order is definitely what you would expect, i.e. numberOfSections followed by numberOfItemsInSection followed by cellForIndexPath, etc. I say "typically" because the rendering of a cell is highly optimized to only happen when necessary, and if you have anything unusual in your view hierarchy or transitions it's possible that it won't ask for cells *immediately* because they wouldn't be visible anyway.